# layout_weight is not working in scroll view

Tags: android

I am trying to use this code but its not working when i put layout weight.If i remove layout weight and enter height for image view,it works fine.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/informative_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.7"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"></ImageView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_option_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6.3" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the reason he has height == 0 is because orientation is vertical

Comment: The child of a ScrollView should also have height wrap_content

Comment: what do you want to achieve? What is the expected result that you want to see?

Comment: height is 0 because i put layout weight

Comment: without scroll view it works fine

Comment: i want to scroll image view with recyclerView

Comment: then why don't you use scrollingActivity instead of this scrollView just add scrollingActivity in your project

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need scrollview. Remove it. And if you are using recyclerview inside scrollview then you need to specify height in dp of list to make it work properly.

Comment: actually i want to scroll image view with recyclerView

Comment: if i put height in dp then it work fine.but i want to know why layout weight is not working properly.